# How Thread.Sleep() works?

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-sleep

So i tried to study how to use multi-threading, and I have noticed something which I don't quite get.

In the next piece of code, it seems like doo() starts running before the Thread  is finished, although foo is the same as the Thread:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    new Thread(new ThreadStart(foo)).Start();
    foo();
    doo();
}

public static void foo()
{

    Console.WriteLine("1");
    Thread.Sleep(3000);
    Console.WriteLine("2");
}

public static void doo()
{
    Console.WriteLine("do");
}
```

The output is:

> 1 //Thread
>
> 1 //foo
>
> 2 //foo
>
> do //doo
>
> 2 //Thread

Assuming that doo() can not start running without foo() is done, we assume that the last "2" output came from the first thread.

How is it possible? Although foo() and the Thread have the same sleeping time since they are the same functions, how come that the Thread (which is executed first) is the last one to finish?

### Lock Statement

Now, if we add a lock statement, like this:

```
static object syncLock = new object();

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    new Thread(new ThreadStart(foo)).Start();
    foo();
    doo();
}

public static void foo()
{
    lock (syncLock)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("1");
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        Console.WriteLine("2");
    }        
}

public static void doo()
{
    Console.WriteLine("do");
}
```

The output is:

> 1 //Thread
>
> 2 //Thread
>
> 1 //foo
>
> do //doo
>
> 2 //Thread

Now it seems like doo() starts running before foo() ends! What is happening here? What is the process and the logic behind it?

Comment: no ... first 1 and 2 are from foo not thread

Comment: Don't forget that Console writes are 'cached'.

Comment: @Selvin Why tho?

Comment: @J.vanLangen What do you mean "cached"?

Comment: `Console.Out.Flush()`

Comment: becuase you would have "1 2 1 2 do" in the other case and if you have "1 2 1 do 2" the first 1 comes from foo not thread ... of course it may run in different ways **so both results are possible**

Comment: But does "lock" blocks the main thread from running?

Comment: but you dont have control over which would be called first: foo from main thread or foo from thread

Comment: @DanielReyhanian It does but only for foo() so when main thread finish foo(), the second thread get in and print "1" + wait 3s, meanwhile the main thread can continue with doo() and on the end (after 3s) the second thread finish foo() too and print "2".

Comment: [in fact with using sync you can have even 3 output versions ...](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qFnayB)

Comment: with this code on fidlle mostly you have: `1m, 2m, 1t, do, 2t` or `1m, 2m, do, 1t, 2t` ... on PC I had also `1t, 2t, 1m, 2m, do`

Comment: with first code you have 6 possibilities `1m, 1t , 2m, 2t, do`, `1m, 1t , 2m, do, 2t`,  `1m, 1t, 2t, 2m, do`, `1t, 1m , 2t, 2m, do`, `1t, 1m , 2m, do, 2t`,  `1t, 1m, 2m, 2t, do`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look, you have here actually two threads, on main and the second thread(foo()) ..
After **new Thread(new ThreadStart(foo)).Start();** executing will start with main thread, that mean this thread(main thread) will try to call foo(), that is your "1" , after that, main thread go to sleep and second thread star foo() , that is second-one "1" ,and sec go to sleep.. Now main thread will wake up and will finish the job "2", "do", and the last "2" is from sec thread. That is without a locking.

With locking, main thread will do foo() and the sec will be blocked("1",3sec,"2"), when foo() is unlock that mean, sec thread can call foo(), and when that happens sec print "1" ad go to sleep, and now(while sec is sleeping CPU looking for thread that can be executed), so CPU exe a main thread and print a "do" and then sec will wake up and print "2"..

Comment: Why the Main Thread is executed before the foo() Thread tho? Because of the sleep?

Comment: Always in OS you have a race conditions, and every time when you work something with thread you need to be careful because of that! You don't know witch thread will first get to function or to variable.. Maybe 10000 times main thread will be faster but 10001 time sec thread will get first the function. Because of that you need to use semaphore or monitor to try to do a synchronization.